# Shiny server error: content-type

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building my first Shiny app based on [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html) basic example. The app reads a spreadsheet from google docs to create a dataframe. The app then displays the whole table by default, but this can be changed through user input. The user can select values for three columns, and the app redraws the table based on the selection.

The app runs nicely locally and it publishes to shinyapps.io without issues. However, when accessed through the browser the only thing I get is the error message posted below the code. Any help to figure out the origin of the error message and how to fix this would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(ggplot2)

# Get data
parksSheet <- gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M7dILNgvCePPlHv5TX4R6pszZX2z9--zOoQSdihfcAk/edit?usp=sharing")
parks <- gs_read(parksSheet)

# Define a server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- parks
    if (input$Governorate != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Governorate == input$Governorate,]
    }
    if (input$Location != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Location == input$Location,]
    }
    if (input$Date_Open != "All") {
      data <- data[data$Date_Open == input$Date_Open,]
    }
    data
  }))

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googlesheets)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
library(ggplot2)

# Get spreadsheet from google docs 
parksSheet <- gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M7dILNgvCePPlHv5TX4R6pszZX2z9--zOoQSdihfcAk/edit?usp=sharing")
parks <- gs_read(parksSheet)

# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Urban Parks Bh"),

    # First row for selectInputs
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             selectInput("Governorate",
                         "Governorate:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(parks$Governorate))))
      ),
      column(4,
             selectInput("Location",
                         "Location:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(parks$Location))))
      ),
      column(4,
             selectInput("Date_Open",
                         "Date Open:",
                         c("All",
                           unique(as.character(parks$Date_Open))))
      )
    ),
    # Create row for the table.
    fluidRow(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: Expected content-type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8 Actual content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: I cant read the file, at all. It gives me the same error. Have you checked [this](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets/issues/259)?

Comment: @Sumedh, you are right, it is a googlesheets issue. With a csv it works fine. Thank you for the link.